# How to interpret the children_left attributes in sklearn decision tree tree_

Tags: tree, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am trying to extract the rules for the deepest nodes using the 'tree_' method in sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier. I have a hard time understand what the 'children_left' and 'children_right' arrays mean from the model. Can anyone help to explain?

```
estimator = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=4, random_state=0)
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
estimator.tree_.children_left

[6] array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5, -1, -1,  8, -1, -1, 11, 12, -1, -1, 15, -1, -1,
   18, 19, 20, -1, -1, 23, -1, -1, 26, 27, -1, -1, 30, -1, -1, 33, 34,
   35, 36, -1, -1, 39, -1, -1, 42, 43, -1, -1, 46, -1, -1, 49, 50, 51,
   -1, -1, 54, -1, -1, 57, 58, -1, -1, 61, -1, -1])

tree_model.tree_.children_right

[7] array([32, 17, 10,  7,  6, -1, -1,  9, -1, -1, 14, 13, -1, -1, 16, -1, -1,
   25, 22, 21, -1, -1, 24, -1, -1, 29, 28, -1, -1, 31, -1, -1, 48, 41,
   38, 37, -1, -1, 40, -1, -1, 45, 44, -1, -1, 47, -1, -1, 56, 53, 52,
   -1, -1, 55, -1, -1, 60, 59, -1, -1, 62, -1, -1])
```

In Sklearn's example, http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html, it says:

```
`# The decision estimator has an attribute called tree_  which stores the    entire
# tree structure and allows access to low level attributes. The binary tree
# tree_ is represented as a number of parallel arrays. The i-th element of  each
# array holds information about the node `i`. Node 0 is the tree's root. NOTE:
# Some of the arrays only apply to either leaves or split nodes, resp.`
```

But it doesn't explain the meaning of the numbers in children_left array

Answer (score 6):

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
iris = load_iris()
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
children_left = clf.tree_.children_left
print (children_left)
```

It prints :

```
[ 1 -1  3  4  5 -1 -1  8 -1 10 -1 -1 13 14 -1 -1 -1]
```

You can find 17 Node decision tree on iris data in google. See it and compare it with the interpretation.

**Now comes the interpretation:**

- It only represents left child node of a node.
- If the value is -1 then it represents that node does not have a left node. It is then leaf node of that decision tree. Here we can see there is 9 leaf nodes.
- If the value is >0 then it has left node. Hence it is not a leaf node.Here 8 nodes are not leaf nodes.

  - Root has one left node. It is 1.
  - now 1 does not have any left node. So it is leaf node. Hence -1.If a node does not have left node, it is also increase node count to 1. So now node count is 2.
  - Now we backtrack to root. Then we go to root's right node. It has left node. Now node count is 3.
  - node 3 has another left node. Node count 4.
  - node 4 has another left node. Node count 5.
  - Node 5 does not have any left node. So it is leaf and shows -1. But now node count is 6.
  - we backtrack to Node 4. We go to it's right child. Again it doesn't have any left child. So it is leaf and shows -1. Node count 7.
  - We again backtrack to Node 3. We go to it's right child. This node has left node. So now Node count is 8.

It goes on. Hope you got the interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

from the post: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/4907029b1ddff16b111c501ad010d5207e0bd177/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx

```
   children_left : array of int, shape [node_count]
    children_left[i] holds the node id of the left child of node i.
    For leaves, children_left[i] == TREE_LEAF. Otherwise,
    children_left[i] > i. This child handles the case where
    X[:, feature[i]] <= threshold[i].
children_right : array of int, shape [node_count]
    children_right[i] holds the node id of the right child of node i.
    For leaves, children_right[i] == TREE_LEAF. Otherwise,
    children_right[i] > i. This child handles the case where
    X[:, feature[i]] > threshold[i].
```

Answer (score 0):

just to show you a little hack with visualizing decision trees. You can specify a parameter node_ids = True in the plotting function of your choice (in my case, export_graphviz), and it will display node-ids on the image of your tree!

```
    export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data, node_ids=True, 
            filled=True, rounded=True,
            special_characters=True,feature_names = feature_cols,class_names=['0','1'])
```

[Iris_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEMUL.png)

!!! :)